# How to continue executing groovy script in Soap UI even if one query insertion fails?

Tags: soapui

Below Query is meant to insert master data in DB: If data is already there well and good I don't want to insert that and continue executing rest all queries.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql


def props = [user: 'testing', password: 'testing', allowMultiQueries: 'true'] as Properties

def url = 'jdbc:mysql://161.91.235.239:3306/cf_85329a15_7ba0_44bb_a289_4ba9be98e661'

def driver = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'

def sql = Sql.newInstance(url, props, driver)

sql.execute """

INSERT INTO `responses` (`ResponseID`,`RequestID`,`UnitSystemID`,`ResponseDateTime`,`UserID`,`UserSubscriptionID`,`ApplicationID`,`PropositionID`,`FeedDefinitionID`,`ObservationID`,`ResponseRAW`) VALUES (100000,0,1,'2015-01-13 07:48:00',1584,1,1,3,1,100008,'test');

INSERT INTO `responses` (`ResponseID`,`RequestID`,`UnitSystemID`,`ResponseDateTime`,`UserID`,`UserSubscriptionID`,`ApplicationID`,`PropositionID`,`FeedDefinitionID`,`ObservationID`,`ResponseRAW`) VALUES (100001,0,1,'2015-01-13 07:48:00',1584,1,1,3,1,500001,'test');

INSERT INTO `responses` (`ResponseID`,`RequestID`,`UnitSystemID`,`ResponseDateTime`,`UserID`,`UserSubscriptionID`,`ApplicationID`,`PropositionID`,`FeedDefinitionID`,`ObservationID`,`ResponseRAW`) VALUES (100002,0,1,'2015-01-13 07:48:00',1584,1,1,3,1,100007,'test');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can checks if your data exists into table before insert. You should do like
 that:

```
import java.util.arrays
import groovy.sql.Sql

def props = [user: 'testing', password: 'testing', allowMultiQueries:   'true'] as Properties

def url =   'jdbc:mysql://161.91.235.239:3306/cf_85329a15_7ba0_44bb_a289_4ba9be98e661'

def driver = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'

def sql = Sql.newInstance(url, props, driver)
def resulSelectValues = sql.execute "select distinct(`ResponseID`) from responses"
def tabQueryValues = {
{100000,0,1,'2015-01-13 07:48:00',1584,1,1,3,1,100008,'test'},     
{100001,0,1,'2015-01-13 07:48:00',1584,1,1,3,1,500001,'test'},
{100002,0,1,'2015-01-13 07:48:00',1584,1,1,3,1,100007,'test'}

for (i=0;i<3;i++)
{
if(!Arrays.asList(resulSelectValues ).contains(tabQueryValues[i,0]))
{
sql.execute """
insert into responses` 
(`ResponseID`,`RequestID`,`UnitSystemID`,`ResponseDateTime`,
`UserID`,`UserSubscriptionID`,`ApplicationID`,`PropositionID`,
`FeedDefinitionID`,`ObservationID`,`ResponseRAW`) values ("""
 +tabQueryValues[i,0]+","+tabQueryValues[i,1]+","+tabQueryValues[i,2]
 +","+tabQueryValues[i,3]+","+tabQueryValues[i,4]+
  ","+tabQueryValues[i,5]+","+tabQueryValues[i,6]+",
"+tabQueryValues[i,7]+","+tabQueryValues[i,8]+",
"+tabQueryValues[i,9]+","+tabQueryValues[i,10]);" 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using just a simple try..catch?

```
try {
    sql.execute """
} catch(SQLException ex) {
    // data already exists, do nothing
}
```